# Different tab size and aligment behavior on Sublime Text 2 on Windows and OSX

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'me using Sublime on a Mac at home and I use it often in my work on a Windows PC.

I'm having some issues with the tab size, the settings are equal but the behavior is very different, alongside with it Alignment plugin does not align properly and when I open aligned files on my Mac they are not aligned.

I am also unable to "hide" divs that are not in the first tab on the document (if it is indented then I cannot hide it)

Does anyone knows how can I fix this issues?

I have searched all the settings and Sublime forum but no luck

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, you should post one question per question on StackOverflow.com, with exact examples what is the actual issue. Now this is random issues bunches together and I will only answer one.

Most likely your Windows and OSX have different configurations (or plugins) how to tabs are handled, even though you think it is the same. So I suggest you paste your configuration files.

Sublime indentation settings are documented here:

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html

Here is an example configuration how to sanitize tab key to always indent with 4 spaces and ignore possible indentation settings Sublime Text tries to guess from the file (taken from this blog post):

```
// Tab and whitespace handling.
// Indent using spaces, 4 spaces ber indent by default, clean up extra whitespaces on save
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"trim_automatic_white_space": true,
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,

// Do not try to detect the tab size from the opened file
"detect_indentation" : false,
```

[More about how tab character vs. space character appear in the text files (subjectional)](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/13/never-use-hard-tabs/).